# Ionic start new project gives ETIMEDOUT with proxy setting

Tags: git, proxy, http-proxy, ionic3

Fetching [app base](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
? Downloading - failed!
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

with ionic info I am getting this info

[image]

I tried setting proxy for the system, github, ionic.

Comment: Could you solve it? I'm with same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Elevated command prompt

```
 npm config set proxy=http://myproxy:8080 
 npm config set https_proxy=http://myproxy:8080
```